# Ember Data - rollback if navigating away from a form

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My application has new / edit forms for a set of entities read from a backend.

When I open such a form, and fill out / edit some fields, then navigate away, the records appear changed in the entity lists, even though I did not commit those changes. Reloading the app (which reloads the data from the backend) fixes the issue, but  is not an option.

I've tried doing some transaction rollbacks in the form view's willDestroyElement, but this seems fundamentally wrong since it gets called even after successful form submits (and actually crashes with `Attempted to handle event rollback on X while in state rootState.loaded.updated.inFlight`).

How would I go about ignoring all unsubmitted form changes (similar to pressing the Cancel button, which performs a transaction rollback), for any use case that involves navigating away from the forms?

Using Ember rc5, Ember Data 0.13.

Answer (score 4):

When exiting the form route, check the state of the record. If its (isNew OR isDirty) and its NOT isSaving, rollback:

```
App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  deactivate: function() {
    var model = this.controllerFor('form');
    if ( (model.get('isNew') || model.get('isDirty')) && (!model.get('isSaving')) ) {
      model.rollback();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm a ember-newbie, but in the new versions of ember you must use `model.rollback();` not `model.get('transaction').rollback();` (the `model.get('transaction')` returns _null_)

Comment: We can also use `this.controller.content` as well.