# Ember: Automatically destroy uncommited new model instance when navigating away from route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `/posts/new` route for creating a new `post` record. I am using the [ember-form-for](https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for) add-on, which provides helpers for creating forms. You are supposed to pass the `form-for` component an object, and when you submit the form, `form-for` calls the `save()` method on the object. So it looks like you're supposed to pass it an instance of a model directly.

This means that I need to create a new `post` model instance automatically when I navigate to this route. This is all good so long as I submit the form and create the new model instance. But what if I go to this route and then leave without submitting (i.e. saving) the new instance? It seems this will leave an unsaved model instance lying around in the store. Do I need to manually destroy this instance if I navigate away from the route, or is there some more elegant way to do this? If I do need to manually destroy it, what's the appropriate hook? `deactivate` is a route method but my new instance is stored on the controller.

NOTE: I've seen [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672323/ember-data-rollback-if-navigating-away-from-a-form), but it's from 2013. Wondering if there's something cleaner available now.

Comment: `deactivate` is good. Or just keep it and reuse it when the user returns. You can access the controller from the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are creating a new model, you need to manually destroy it (roll it back). This can be done in the route's `resetController` hook. Something like below:

```js
// Your route.js file
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { get } from '@ember/object';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return get(this, 'store').createRecord('some-model');
  },
  resetController(controller, isExiting) {
    if (isExiting) {
      get(controller, 'model').rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
});
```

Refer: https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttributes?anchor=rollbackAttributes